# Kubernetes service not working (Timing out)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

My service is not connecting/directing traffic to pod. I have 'sshed' into the pod and the server is working properly but the service times out.

Deployment File:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: venues
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: venues
        version: v0.3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: venues
        image: some-image
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
          name: http-server
```

Service File:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: venues
  labels:
    name: venues
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: venues
```

Comment: if you execute `kubectl get svc` or `kubectl get deployments` what do you get ?

Comment: > kubectl get deployments: venues    1         1         1            1           2h

Comment: > kubectl get svc: venues       ip1    ip2   3000:31412/TCP                                 2h

Comment: I would:
- remove the deployment.
- remove the service : `kubectl delete service fooService' (or something like that)

Then: 
- create the deployment again by doing : `kubectl create -f deploymentfile.yml`
- expose the service using expose : `kubectl expose foodployment --type=LoadBalancer ` for example

Comment: This way, the service is created for you from a deployment.

Comment: So that worked, what now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector in the service is wrong: you need to select a label of the deployment, not the container name. So

```
selector:
  app: venues
```

should work. Optionally you could add also `version: v0.3` if needed.